Thesis part was flagged as AI generated even though it is all original
So this happened to a friend of mine who is attending a business school and just handed in his thesis to his supervisor. The supervisor checked it with "Turnitin" and it gave a result of 20% of the thesis seems to be AI generated even though he wrote it all himself through months.
The supervisor who is the school's director then told him with this result he places him under academic probation and if the result is not under 5% when he hands it in again he will kick him out of the school and nullify all his coursework and his degree and thesis...
He doesn't even hear his arguments, just says he doesn't have the time to listen to him and his decision is final.
My friend doesn't have access to turnitin do he could check the changes he makes to the thesis.
Currently he is using 5 different ai checkers to try to find the paragraphs that flagged as AI and change/rephrase the whole thesis...
Any ideas how to approach this better?

Is this a large school with a national (or international) student body, or a small place with only local students?

Which country is this?

Did your friend use a tool like Grammarly to help edit their thesis?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Your friend will never receive a value under 5% unless it is 0%. As of September, the Turnitin website explains the new policy: "To avoid potential incidence of false positives, no score or highlights are attributed for AI detection scores in the 1% to 19% range. When AI is detected below the 20% threshold in the report, it is now indicated with an asterisk (*%) and no percentage is attributed."

Is "20%" meant to indicate that 20% of the text was generated, or that there's a 20% probability that some of it was generated? (Either way, the supervisor is an idiot, but if it's the latter, the argument's slightly easier.)

There was a recent story on Bloomberg: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2024-10-18/do-ai-detectors-work-students-face-false-cheating-accusations about an epidemic of false accusations.

I'd appeal, through whatever system the university has. Your friend should arm themselves with citations of the various groups who have tested "AI detectors" and found them incredibly unreliable.
Before doing so, your friend should check for any policies that the school has about either use of GenAI by students or "detection" of GenAI. This will tell them whether they are appealing the supervisor's actions, or the university's policy. The latter will probably be more difficult.
Obviously, your friend should first consider whether they did use AI to write substantive parts of the work, unless there is a policy that allows this.

About that last para, yes. I feel like there's an 80% chance if OP read their friend's thesis they'd realize this isn't how they talk or write. Why lie to your friend? It seems like part of the process, maybe as part of an  "everyone does it" environment. When people are kicked out of on-line games for hacking they often jump into the forums to complain how innocent they are.

And watch out for not just writing significant portions, but AI copy-editing.  This could conceivably fall foul of Turnitin's mystery AI detection tool, while being little more use to the student than a conventional spelling & grammar checker

@OwenReynolds How are you calculating an 80% chance that OPs friend used AI (am I misinterpreting your comment?)? AI checkers straight up suck.  The whole point of AI is to make sentences that sound like a human wrote them, and these checkers really seem to fail at telling the difference between the two.  In my experience telling if something is AI usually has to do with finding odd patterns in paragraphs, but I'm not sure how the checker would look for that, or how it could come up with a %.  I'd think at best they can flag for you to take a better look, but using it to determine guilt is bad

@JMac I'm saying this feels like their friend was caught cheating (and they can easily read the paper and decide for themselves). I don't think AI even matters here. We're had plagiarism checkers for a while, after all.

@OwenReynolds But a plagiarism checker is looking for something totally different than an AI checker.  Checking for plagiarism is checking for use of existing work, typically already published somewhere.  AI on the other hand can combine words to make novel sentences, depending on the prompt.  There's just no way to check it in the same way a plagiarism checker would.  Also, as far as I understand it, it's still good to actually review the results from the plagiarism checker and not assume it flawless.  But if it points out what is plagiarized and where it's from, you can check

You dont get the same type of report from an AI checker, so you cant even manually verify that its not a false positive.

@OwenReynolds , nobody understand the generative AI, If OP had said 20% was plagiarised then I'd be inclined to believe their friend had been cheating. But I wouldn't trust an AI checker until the companies that make these AIs start putting fingerprinting into anything generated. Since we know nothing about how an AI differs from a human, and the companies probably aren't giving access to their models, the best turnitin is probably checking for is a genericness that tends to appear in AI text. I do wonder if the BS that students learn to write that says nothing but seems good would trigger it.

20% isn't even that high a score... this whole thing feels pretty overblown to me.

@OwenReynolds Our university did some research into Turnitin's AI checker. The results were so bad, that not just do the not require, or even recommend using it. Its banned.

Something else to keep in mind whilst marshaling resources:  find old versions of the work.  For example, Google Docs have a version history, and you might be able to find past versions of a document somewhere in the MS Word menus.  Or if you make regular backups or use DropBox, you may be able to find earlier versions.  If such versions exist, they can show the process by which the paper was written, which can give evidence toward the work being human written rather than LLM written.

@NAMcMahon at 20% "plagiarised" on Turnitin I'd look, but (in physics undergrad dissertations) expect to find that's nearly all made up of standard terminology and the bibliography, with just a few slightly longer examples that could easily be different writers converging on the same sentence to describe the same thing. I have seen a few fairly heavily plagiarised pieces of work, and the number was only a little greater, but the size of the blocks in a single colour (matching a single source) much larger

@NAMcMahon: just FYI the checker works by comparing the statistical likelihood of particular words following other particular words and comparing that to the statistics from GPT-3 (and other LLMs) rather than any "genericness".

Fair warning, I don't believe that there is any justifiable and ethical use of "ai detectors".  In truth, I believe that relying on them even in part cannot be done ethically, because the chances of false positives are too high, and the students are then thrown into a position where there is a presumption against them, and it is nearly impossible to prove a negative.
However, my opinion isn't going to help your friend.  Here are some more useful avenues that he might take.
The traditional advise is to throw the professor's work into a plagiarism detector and show them what portion of their work was AI generated - it can certainly be eye-opening to find that the model believes that 40% of a paper you wrote in the 1990's is AI-generated, and hopefully this sort of action is enough to persuade a professor that relying on AI so-called detectors is misguided.
If your friend worked in Google Docs, then as long as he really did his own work, he can use an extension like WriteHuman or any other extension that shows a full playback of the edits to the document to demonstrate that he wrote it himself.  The things they'd want to watch out for is very sequential writing, as if he is simply typing everything while copying from another source, or chunks of text that appear out of nowhere; both of those are possible indicators of cheating.
Finally, if your friend has chatGPT plus, he can offer to show them his chatGPT history as ancillary evidence.  Since chats can be deleted, it's not a panacea, but you can show how you use ChatGPT responsibly in general as a bit of suggestive, side-evidence.
At some point, universities will have to realize that detectors are fundamentally unreliable and unethical, because they are unacceptably likely to tar the innocent as guilty, but until then, the best you can do as an individual is to try to demonstrate your own innocence, and to lobby the schools to ban such unreliable panaceas.

I would think that if you used chatGPT, and then paraphrased the transcript without citation, then that's plagiaristic.

@ScottSeidman  It absolutely would be. I don't think I suggested otherwise.

Your friend should work with the department or others to get turnitin reports, and then modify their thesis in order to get their business degree.
It may not be the most satisfying approach, but it's the approach that will yield a degree expediently, with least effort, and highest probability of success.

I disagree with this as it just foists the problem onto someone else. Sure, it's the path of least resistance but: 1) essentially functions as an admission of guilt and 2) perpetuates the problem.

@ScottishTapWater it isn't the responsibility of a graduating student to improve their department's processes.

Good answer, but to address @ScottishTapWater’s “admission of guilt” criticism, what the friend can do is to comply with the demand to modify the thesis, but to also submit alongside the revised thesis a note stating something like: “I have complied with your requirement to pass the AI detection check. For the record, I would like to state that I never used AI assistance at any point when writing my thesis. My efforts to revise the thesis in order to pass the AI detection test were a pointless waste of time and do not constitute an admission that I used AI assistance prior to that.”

@JohnMadden - I'm not sure I agree with that either, it's everyone's responsibility

And what does the friend do when they modify everything Turnitin flagged as AI-generated and resubmit the thesis, only for Turnitin to once again flag 20% (probably even a different 20% this time) as AI-generated?

@JanusBahsJacquet -- sorry -- "get Turnitin reports" refers to a real time ability to get Turnitin reports.

My point was that the unreliability and general randomness of AI reporting (for which Turnitin itself uses AI) means there’s absolutely no guarantee that the same text will give the same report twice. Even if the student repeatedly runs the thesis through Turnitin until it goes below 5%, the advisor may still get 15% when he runs the exact same document through.

Defamation suit
If pursuing this through university channels does not work, it could be brought into civil court.
The claims of AI generator usage clearly "injures reputation" and "causes a legally redressable injury". In the court this is what your friend's lawyer would need to prove.
The opposite side lawyer could try to claim one of the defences, most typically that the claim is true. However proving the AI usage to court standards would be challenging. It will help if your friend can provide opposing evidence, such as intermediate versions.

Who would this be directed against? There doesn’t seem to be a third party in whose eyes the student reputation is damaged. Turnitin likely only creates a (likelihood or similar) score, not a true/false verdict. The university is unlikely to disclose the rejection reason, though if their rules are worth their salt they will similarly only be about the score and not claim AI fraud was actually committed.

@MisterMiyagi If the supervisor makes the decision by themselves and passes it to the university, I'd sue them. I agree that it becomes more complex if it is a board decision. Some past cases involving false plagiarism claims: 1, 2. The latter was on different grounds than defamation though.

Both of these sources are about the accusation being published, not (just) about the accusation itself. Based on what the OP has disclosed, the supervisor did not publish the accusation and made it clear the issue is about the score, not AI usage in itself (as indicated by the requirement to get the score below an arbitrary threshold).

"he will kick him out of the school and nullify all his coursework and his degree and thesis" sounds like it would involve publication.

It will also be fairly easy to show the professor behaved recklessly.

This assumes that a judge would be less clueless about language modeling and the detectors than the supervisor is. Not necessarily a safe assumption.

@jpa. The prof can't pass this to the university, the prof largely is the university or at least an agent of the university.

I'm no lawyer, but it sounds like the GDPR law might be of help in this instance. It prohibits "decision based solely on automated processing" which it sounds like it is in this case. It would at least force the supervisor to motivate why he personally think it is AI-generated. And well, as someone who have used turnitin from both sides, it is a useful tool, but one HAS to be aware that it is just a tool, and that all AI-detection systems are heuristics, there is no way to detect with 100% confidence that a text was auto-generated.
Your friend might want to run his text against the myriad of validators available online to see where they complain.
Some useful notes:

OpenAI's own old classifier was to unreliable (and they are like the current star in AI-stuff)
New AI classifier for indicating AI-written text
They haven't released their new watermarking/classifying algorithm:
OpenAI Has a Tool to Detect When Students Use ChatGPT to Cheat


GDPR is for private/personal data. It doesn’t mean that no one is allowed to make decisions based solely on automated processing in general. Even then, unless feeding the thesis to Turnitin, parsing the result, and triggering the suspension/penalty/… happens fully automated then even for data in scope of GDPR this section would not apply.

People often think GDPR applies to all data generated by a human. It does not, it only deals with personal data, so data about a person that can be uniquely linked to a natural person. So this might deal with insurance companies that use medical records to determine the insurance premium.
